# Is there a way I can create library that can be used by .NET and Python?

Tags: python, .net-core

I have a use-case where I want to create a library that can be consumed by Python and .NET Core.
I just want to write code once and maintain in a single repository.

Comment: Without some rather arcane bridging one way or the other (i.e. Python calling out to .NET code, or .NET running Python), no.

Comment: Perhaps [IronPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython) is what you're looking for?